# Spring MVC 4.0 RESTFul Web Services

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to build a hello world restful web service with the help of spring mvc 4.0 framework. I created a dynamic web application added web.xml , rest-servlet.xml and MyController.java file in a package mythird.attempt.sample.controller.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

    <display-name>My sample rest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <context:component-scan base-package="mythird.attempt.sample.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

  </beans>
```

MyController.java

```
package mythird.attempt.sample.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myfirst")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String name) {
      String result="Hello "+name;  
      return result;
     }

    @RequestMapping(value="/qq", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
     public String getGreeting1() {
      String result="Hello world";  
      return result;
     }
}
```

I tried deploying this on both apache tomcat and glassfish. 
When i hit the url "localhost:8080//.../myfirst/asdf in the browser
Glassfish gave warnings like 
"No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myfirst/asdf] in DispatcherServlet with name.."

And gave a dialog with details and ok , on clicking details

it gives

System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from localhost:8080/TestApache1/myfirst/kk: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

Please help me out here!!. thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..
Things started working fine when i used the normal browser instead of embedded browser in my eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you building this project?

Answer (score 0):

I think the url should be "localhost:8080/{warname}/rest/myfirst/asdf

The web.xml says that the servlet will kick in for all url's that have a "rest" path in it, i do not think you are using that in your sample attempts

Comment: i am using war name while accessing it(just mentioned it in dots instead of typing name) .. no the url in web.xml is /* so adding rest as you said didnt help me